# Flex 4.6 : Make action for button in list

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.5, mxml

I'm beginner in Flex . my issue when to add button to list , i put the button in the itemrender but the action of `navigator.pushView(views.Listde,ProblemsList.selectedItem);`
 make an error "Acess of undefined property navigator .

Code :

```
<s:ItemRenderer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark">
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import views.ButList;

        protected function button1_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            navigator.pushView(views.Listde,ProblemsList.selectedItem);
        }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<s:Group width="100%" height="100%" styleName="PCS.css">
    <s:HGroup width="100%" height="100%" gap="2" verticalAlign="middle" horizontalAlign="center" paddingBottom="5" paddingLeft="5"
              paddingRight="5" paddingTop="5">
        <s:HGroup width="30%" height="100%" verticalAlign="middle" horizontalAlign="center">
            <s:Label text="{data._AddedDate}" textAlign="left" verticalAlign="bottom" width="100%" height="100%"/>
        </s:HGroup>
        <s:VGroup width="50%" height="100%" verticalAlign="middle" horizontalAlign="right">
            <s:BitmapImage source="images/{data.image}"/>
            <s:TextArea editable="false" text="{data.description}"/>
            <s:Label text="{data.price}"/>
            <s:Button label="s" click="button1_clickHandler(event)"/>                   
        </s:VGroup>
    </s:HGroup>
</s:Group>
```

if any solution to resolve it by list or any component instead of list then i want button to navigate to view with the selected item and the change of the list to navigate to another view with the selected item also , then the change of list work success but the button action cannot defined with the navigator.

Thanks in advance for any help .

Comment: navigator to navigate to another view by name of the view

Comment: Ok, well flex doesn't know what it is either, where is this navigator?And what type is it?

Comment: the type of it is spark.components.View.navigator():ViewNavigator 
and i dont know how to define to it its type i try to import spark.components and still not defined when i type navigator the declared types are navigateToURL() , NavigationUnit and NavigatorContent only not have navigator.

Comment: It cannont find navigator because its defined in another class, you an event to retrieve the navigator or if the navigator is in the main app class use
    FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.navigator

You can access your main class using FlexGlobals, event though Adobe recommend you not to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a custom event with data property and dispatch the event from item renderer or dispatch the list change event from the item renderer when clicking the button.

```
package myEvents
{
import flash.events.Event;

public class CustomEvent extends Event
{
    public function CustomEvent(type:String, 
        data:Object=null) {
            // Call the constructor of the superclass.
            super(type);

            // Set the new property.
            this.data = data;
    }

    // Define static constant.
    public static const MY_BUTTON_CLICKED:String = "myButtonClicked";

    // Define a public variable to hold the state of the enable property.
    public var data:Object;

    // Override the inherited clone() method.
    override public function clone():Event {
        return new CustomEvent(type, data);
    }
  }
}
```

**MyItemRenderer.mxml**

```
<s:ItemRenderer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
            xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark">
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import views.ButList;

        protected function button1_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            // dispatch a custom
            (this.owner as List).dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent(CustomEvent.MY_BUTTON_CLICKED, data));
            //navigator.pushView(views.Listde,ProblemsList.selectedItem);
        }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<s:Group width="100%" height="100%" styleName="PCS.css">
    <s:HGroup width="100%" height="100%" gap="2" verticalAlign="middle" horizontalAlign="center" paddingBottom="5" paddingLeft="5"
              paddingRight="5" paddingTop="5">
        <s:HGroup width="30%" height="100%" verticalAlign="middle" horizontalAlign="center">
            <s:Label text="{data._AddedDate}" textAlign="left" verticalAlign="bottom" width="100%" height="100%"/>
        </s:HGroup>
        <s:VGroup width="50%" height="100%" verticalAlign="middle" horizontalAlign="right">
            <s:BitmapImage source="images/{data.image}"/>
            <s:TextArea editable="false" text="{data.description}"/>
            <s:Label text="{data.price}"/>
            <s:Button label="s" click="button1_clickHandler(event)"/>                   
        </s:VGroup>
    </s:HGroup>
</s:Group>
```

**Your view class**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
title="MY View">
<s:layout>
    <s:VerticalLayout paddingTop="10"/>
</s:layout>

<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import spark.events.IndexChangeEvent;

        private function onListCreationComplete_Handler():void
        {
            myList.addEventListener(CustomEvent.MY_BUTTON_CLICKED, onItemRendererButtonClicked);
        }

        protected function onItemRendererButtonClicked(event:CustomEvent):void {
            var data:Object = event.data;
            navigator.pushView(views.Listde,data);//myList.selectedItem
        }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<s:Label text="Select an view"/>
<s:List id="myList"
    width="100%" height="100%"
    labelField="firstName" itemRenderer="MyItemRenderer"
    change="myList_changeHandler(event)" creationComplete="onListCreationComplete_Handler()">
    <s:ArrayCollection>
        <fx:Object description="Fruits" image="assets/icons/1.png" _AddedDate="15/05/14" price="154"/>
        <fx:Object description="New Item" image="assets/icons/2.png" _AddedDate="15/05/14" price="154"/>
         <fx:Object description="Doll" image="assets/icons/3.png" _AddedDate="15/05/14" price="154"/>
    </s:ArrayCollection>
</s:List>
</s:View>
```

I hope this might help u. There are tons of examples out there for list and item renderer for mobile.

Comment: +1 nice answer.  Note that you could also use the built-in `DataEvent` with the `selectedIndex` of the list instead of a custom event with the `selectedItem`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your `ItemRenderer`, you can simply listen to the `IndexChangeEvent` in your `View`.  In this case, you don't need a separate button at all - the whole `ItemRenderer` can act as the button.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
title="MY View">
    <s:layout>
        <s:VerticalLayout paddingTop="10"/>
    </s:layout>

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import spark.events.IndexChangeEvent;
            import views.ButList;

            protected function myList_changeHandler(event:IndexChangeEvent):void {
                navigator.pushView(views.Listde,myList.selectedItem);
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:Label text="Select an view"/>
    <s:List id="myList"
        width="100%" height="100%"
        labelField="firstName" itemRenderer="MyItemRenderer"
        change="myList_changeHandler(event)">
        <s:ArrayCollection>
            <fx:Object description="Fruits" image="assets/icons/1.png" _AddedDate="15/05/14" price="154"/>
            <fx:Object description="New Item" image="assets/icons/2.png" _AddedDate="15/05/14" price="154"/>
             <fx:Object description="Doll" image="assets/icons/3.png" _AddedDate="15/05/14" price="154"/>
        </s:ArrayCollection>
    </s:List>
</s:View>
```

Comment: Thanks , Yes i used myList.selectedItem .